# calabash-ios simulator stuck at 'launching took xxx seconds'

Tags: calabash, calabash-ios

My simulator is starting up, and showing what looks like a successful launch:

```
Launching took 6.652245 seconds
```

Except the feature file isn't running ... it just sticks there. Could this be in simlauncher? Or maybe I have a config messed up?

It was running ok earlier ... then I ran a few other simulator tasks and it seems to be out of sync.

Thanks in advance !

---

debug info:

```html
  
18:34 $ ./go.sh
Feature: getting started with ios android automation

  Scenario: debug            # features/getting_started.feature:3

INFO: Using uia strategy: 'preferences'
Preparation took 0.110554 seconds
Simulator instruction set 'x86_64' is compatible with ["i386", "x86_64"]
{
                    :app => "/Users/qa/repos/Foo-ios/test_harness/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Foo-cal.app",
                   :args => [],
:bundle_dir_or_bundle_id => "/Users/qa/repos/Foo/test_harness/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Foo-cal.app",
              :bundle_id => "com.foo.bar.Foo-cal",
                 :device => "iphone",
          :device_target => "simulator",
          :launch_method => :instruments,
         :launch_retries => 5,
               :log_file => "/var/folders/6f/tmnbb60j62715sj_n1xt_crr0000gr/T/run_loop20150310-51884-g6i9qx/run_loop.out",
              :no_launch => false,
                :no_stop => false,
                  :reset => false,
            :results_dir => "/var/folders/6f/tmnbb60j62715sj_n1xt_crr0000gr/T/run_loop20150310-51884-g6i9qx",
      :results_dir_trace => "/var/folders/6f/tmnbb60j62715sj_n1xt_crr0000gr/T/run_loop20150310-51884-g6i9qx/trace",
                 :script => "/var/folders/6f/tmnbb60j62715sj_n1xt_crr0000gr/T/run_loop20150310-51884-g6i9qx/_run_loop.js",
            :sdk_version => nil,
                   :udid => "iPhone 5s (8.1 Simulator)",
           :uia_strategy => :preferences,
                  :xcode => "6.1.1",
             :xcode_path => "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer"
}

### Starting on simulator App: /Users/qa/repos/foo/test_harness/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Foo-cal.app ###
2015-03-10 18:35:25 -0700 xcrun instruments -w iPhone 5s (8.1 Simulator) -D /var/folders/6f/tmnbb60j62715sj_n1xt_crr0000gr/T/run_loop20150310-51884-g6i9qx/trace -t Automation /Users/qa/repos/foo/test_harness/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Foo-cal.app -e UIARESULTSPATH /var/folders/6f/tmnbb60j62715sj_n1xt_crr0000gr/T/run_loop20150310-51884-g6i9qx -e UIASCRIPT /var/folders/6f/tmnbb60j62715sj_n1xt_crr0000gr/T/run_loop20150310-51884-g6i9qx/_run_loop.js >& /var/folders/6f/tmnbb60j62715sj_n1xt_crr0000gr/T/run_loop20150310-51884-g6i9qx/run_loop.out
Launching took 6.652245 seconds
```

Comment: looks like the simulator is unresponsive. When I start the simulator manually and click on the app, it's responsive. But launching through cucumber, the app loads, but is unreqponsive.

Comment: annnd ... I have found a fix but not sure what exactly is going on. Looks like there is a bug with UIAutomation when excessive logging is happening and, indeed, our app does dump a lot on initial load. Removing some of that configuration seems to have brought me back to life. It sure does look like a low level freeze in UIA. https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios/wiki/Hot-Topics

Comment: A couple days in, this is indeed caused by the above logging bug. Reducing the verbosity of our logs alleviates the problem.